# Exporting localization data into Xliff file

Tags: c#, localization, xliff

I'm using c# and I want to export xliff file from my localization data base.
how can I do so using code alone without external editors?
is there a simple solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You will simply have to write to a file while looping over the records in your database. I would look into utilizing an XMLWriter class such as this one and it will make your life much easier: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx